# Loading.gif not working after every image is opened-Light box 2

Tags: javascript, css, loading, lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2 in a website I'm developing to pop up images. The loading gif doesn't appear each time an image is loaded. It appears only for the first image and then after,the white screen without the gif appears while loading. Where could I make changes to make it such that the loading.gif is activated everytime an image is opened.

Comment: placing some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the latest version of the plugin. An update was recently fixed for this issue

**info** https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/38